# How to setup a live template in intellij for a new file extension

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, live-templates, intellij-15

I have a new customized file type with new file extension and I want to setup some Live Templates for that file type, Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the settings window, go to Editor-> Live Templates.
Click the "+" icon to add a new Template group, and then add the live templates under that group.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order for the live template to be visible in your customized file type you need to select "Other" when defining the applicable contexts.Please see below:

[image]